# Why is my Django CreateView not adding new recipes to the database?

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms

My Django CreateView doesn't submit data to the database.
I am an absolute beginner when it comes to Django and creating websites and I feel like there's something that i haven't quite understood yet. I tried following tutorials and ended up with a draft of a recipe sharing website for a uni project, but, even thought the other CRUD views can access the database, it looks like the one that's supposed to create a new recipe can not. It does not display any errors, nor show something not working, when I press "Confirm" it justs refreshes the page and doesn't add anything to my database (I'm using Django's default db). This is my code, sorry for the poor quality but I'm doing my best to learn:

Models:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    CATEGORY_CHOICES = [
        ('Easy', 'Easy'),
        ('Medium', 'Medium'),
        ('Hard', 'Hard'),
    ]

    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'recipes'


class Ingredient(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=125)
    amount = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'recipes'


class Recipe(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    description = models.TextField()
    ingredients = models.ManyToManyField(Ingredient, related_name='recipes')
    instructions = models.TextField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("recipes-detail", kwargs={"pk": self.pk})
```

View that won't do its job:

```
class RecipeCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = models.Recipe
    form_class = RecipeForm
    template_name = 'recipes/create_recipe.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def get_form(self, form_class=None):
        form = super().get_form(form_class)
        form.helper = FormHelper()
        form.helper.add_input(Submit('submit', 'Create Recipe'))
        return form
```

Template of the Create Recipe webpage:
(Sorry for the unnecessary JavaScript, I included it just in case, since I feel like my grasp of the problem is too superficial to understand what's actually giving me this issue. Anyway, what it does is create the necessary fields to add a new ingredient to the recipe, since the default form has only one row of text fields used to add one ingredient, the user can then select to add or delete rows to expand or shrink the list of ingredients and their quantities)

```
{% extends 'recipes/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
  <form method="POST" action="{% url 'recipes-create' %}" class="my-form">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <h2 class="form-title">Create Recipe</h2>

    <div class="form-field">
      <label for="{{ form.title.id_for_label }}">Title:</label>
      {{ form.title }}
    </div>

    <div class="form-field">
      <label for="{{ form.category.id_for_label }}">Category:</label>
      {{ form.category }}
    </div>

    <div class="form-field">
      <label for="{{ form.description.id_for_label }}">Description:</label>
      {{ form.description }}
    </div>

     <div id="ingredient-fields">
        <div class="form-field">
            <label for="{{ form.ingredients.id_for_label }}">Ingredients:</label>

            <div id="ingredient-container">
                <div class="ingredient-field">
                    <div class="ingredient-input">
                        <label for="id_ingredients">Ingredient:</label>
                        <input type="text" name="ingredients" id="id_ingredients" value="{{ ingredient.name }}">
                    </div>
                    <div class="ingredient-input">
                        <label for="id_quantity">Quantity:</label>
                        <input type="text" name="quantity" id="id_quantity" value="{{ ingredient.amount }}">
                    </div>
                    <button type="button" class="remove-ingredient">Remove</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <button type="button" id="add-ingredient">Add Ingredient</button>
        </div>
    </div>



    <div class="form-field">
      <label for="{{ form.instructions.id_for_label }}">Instructions:</label>
      {{ form.instructions }}
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="submit-button">Create Recipe</button>

    <div class="border-top pt-3">
      <a class="text-muted" href="{% url 'recipes-home' %}">Cancel</a>
    </div>

  </form>


  <script>
      document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
      const ingredientContainer = document.getElementById("ingredient-container");
      const addIngredientBtn = document.getElementById("add-ingredient");

      function createIngredientField() {
        const ingredientField = document.createElement("div");
        ingredientField.classList.add("ingredient-field");

        const ingredientInput = document.createElement("div");
        ingredientInput.classList.add("ingredient-input");

        const ingredientLabel = document.createElement("label");
        ingredientLabel.setAttribute("for", "id_ingredients");
        ingredientLabel.textContent = "Ingredient:";

        const ingredientInputField = document.createElement("input");
        ingredientInputField.setAttribute("type", "text");
        ingredientInputField.setAttribute("name", "ingredients");
        ingredientInputField.setAttribute("id", "id_ingredients");

        ingredientInput.appendChild(ingredientLabel);
        ingredientInput.appendChild(ingredientInputField);

        const quantityInput = document.createElement("div");
        quantityInput.classList.add("ingredient-input");

        const quantityLabel = document.createElement("label");
        quantityLabel.setAttribute("for", "id_quantity");
        quantityLabel.textContent = "Quantity:";

        const quantityInputField = document.createElement("input");
        quantityInputField.setAttribute("type", "text");
        quantityInputField.setAttribute("name", "quantity");
        quantityInputField.setAttribute("id", "id_quantity");

        quantityInput.appendChild(quantityLabel);
        quantityInput.appendChild(quantityInputField);

        const removeBtn = document.createElement("button");
        removeBtn.setAttribute("type", "button");
        removeBtn.classList.add("remove-ingredient");
        removeBtn.textContent = "Remove";
        removeBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
          ingredientField.remove();
        });

        ingredientField.appendChild(ingredientInput);
        ingredientField.appendChild(quantityInput);
        ingredientField.appendChild(removeBtn);

        return ingredientField;
      }

      addIngredientBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
        const ingredientField = createIngredientField();
        ingredientContainer.appendChild(ingredientField);
      });
    });

  </script>

{% endblock %}
```

Recipe form:

```
class RecipeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Recipe
        fields = ['title', 'author', 'category', 'description', 'ingredients', 'instructions']
```

The urls.py file looks fine and I've tried taking a look at the network requests in the browser's developer tools, and I noticed that the form data is indeed being sent to the server.

Comment: Share the `RecipeForm`.

Comment: Do you have an error message or a response number?.

Comment: No, it doesn't show anything...

Comment: Oh, sorry I forgot to add the RecipeForm, I edited the post and added it now!